# Laravel DB::RAW fetch single

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm using a RAW Query in Laravel.. Because it's seems a bit complicated to do with the query builder or with Eloquent.

I am querying the database for 1 person, By using where on his name.
**The returned result is an array, with an object in it..**
 ( see screenshot )

[image]

### How would i only get the first result? i have tried

```
return $data['person'] = DB::select(DB::raw($person))[0];
```

which gives me the following error:
*The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.*

```
return $data['person'] = DB::select(DB::raw($person))->first();
```

which is telling me that first is not applicable for this kind of query..

### This is the query

```
SELECT nickname, firstname, lastname, age, title, photo, companies.name, cities.name, trickshot
FROM persons
JOIN companies ON companies.id = persons.company_id
JOIN cities ON cities.id =  companies.city_id
WHERE CONCAT(firstname, lastname) = '{$fullname}' AND cities.name = '{$city}'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Fetching first has nothing to do with returning a string. First line works, but you can't return `stdObject` as a response, since it doesn't implement `__toString` method (while Eloquent does). So you have to do it manually, or better use Eloquent.

Comment: Would you maybe know the eloquent way of doing this? I'll add the query to my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it in Eloquent assuming `Person` is the model you need:

```
Person::select( ... , 'comp.name as company', 'cit.name as city')
  ->join('companies as comp', 'comp.id', '=', 'persons.company_id')
  ->join('cities as cit', 'cit.id', '=', 'comp.city_id')
  ->where('cit.name', $city)
  ->where(DB::raw('concat(firstname, lastname)'), $fullname)
  ->first();
```

If you need this data set more often, then I would create a DB view for this instead.